# Jquery file upload plugin - restricting file upload

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, jquery-plugins

i am using jquery file upload plugin for uploading profile images.

```
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" data-url="/users/profile/update/image">
```

and here is my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#image').fileupload({
        singleFileUploads : true,
        acceptFileTypes : /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        maxFileSize : 10,
        done: function(formContainer) {
            console.debug("done");
        }
    });
});
```

But this script is allowing to submit any kind of file. Can anyone kindly help me what is wrong with my code. I have coptied the regular expression from plugin documentation.
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options

I am using Spring 3.2 on server side.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, i am writing the solution if any one else need.

added the following script file

```
jquery.fileupload-validate.js
```

and added folowing script

```
$(document).ready(function){
  $('#image').bind('fileuploadprocessfail', function (e, data) {
            alert(data.files[data.index].error); //it will alert the message.
        });
});
```